# Can Java's == operator be asymmetric for primitive values?

Tags: java, identity

Can Java's `==` operator be **asymmetric** for **primitive** values, so that `x == y`, but `y != x`, where `x` and `y` are both variables of some (**possibly different**) primitive types?

**Edit:**

OK, I'll be honest with the reason why I ask. In the [Java Puzzlers book](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/), there is this puzzle #87 which concerns the `==` operator for primitive types.

It has three parts, one challenges reader to find a case where the `==` operator is not reflective, second is for finding a case where `==` is not transitive. I've found solutions for both of them, but I have no idea how to solve the third one, which is defined like this:

```
public class Symmetric {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*
         * If you can come up with a set of primitive types and values
         * that causes this program to print "true false", then
         * you have proven that the == operator is not symmetric.
         */
        <typeX> x = <valueX>;
        <typeY> y = <valueY>;

        System.out.print ((x == y) + " ");
        System.out.println(y == x);
    }
}
```

I don't own the book, so I cannot look it up for a solution, I only got across the source files, which don't contain the solutions.

Comment: No, it can't be for primitive types.

Comment: Note that what you describe is a bidirectional relationship. Did you mean 'but not y == x'?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the second expression incorrectly. Now it should be obvious.

Comment: The term is "asymmetric". I've edited your post.

Comment: @David: exactly. The == operator is *symmetric* in this situation.

Comment: Additionally, this cannot be asymmetric for non-primitives either.  Of course, .equals() could be asymmetric.

Comment: Why are people being so careful to say _for primitive types_ ... in what scenario is `==` asymmetric?

Comment: The one scenario I would be unsure about that is when x is an integer and y is a double or something like that. Does java convert one of them to the other type when testing ==?

Comment: Umn, no that's absolutely **not** what puzzle #87 is all about. You should read the description again, carefully this time. Also you're aware that the solutions are on the next page?

Comment: @Voo Sadly, I don't own the book. :)

Comment: @Natix well then quick summary. It's about proving that not all primitives can be split into equivalence classes. This means they have to be reflexive, transitive and symmetric. Symmetry holds for all primitives, but they're not reflexive (`NaN != NaN`). It also violates transitivity: That is because converting ints/longs to floats/doubles loses precision.

Comment: @Voo So the book says that the _Transitive_ and _Relfexive_ puzzle both have a solution (which I've found and they are the same as you've written), but the _Symmetric_ puzzle does not have one?

Comment: @Natix Yep. need 3 more chars.

Comment: Knowing Josh Bloch I'm sure that this has a solution (weird and unexpected one )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` Is symmetric for **every** type...

From the spec:

> The equality operators are commutative if the operand expressions have no side
>   effects.

Comment: *should* be symmetric for every type.  A silly person could define an override that wasn't...

Comment: @Wug there is no way to do that in Java.

Comment: @Wug: From your tags it would seem to be [java] itself :P http://stackoverflow.com/users/1462604/wug?tab=tags

Comment: Really big sample size you got there. :D

Answer (score 4):

No. For all primitives, the == sign is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). That is,

(x == y) => (y == x)

Comment: The [commutative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) sounds like the correct term to me. "In mathematics, a binary operation is commutative if changing the order of the operands does not change the result"

Answer (score 4):

There is a only are a few special values for equality and comparison.  These are Float.NaN, Double.NaN, -0.0f and -0.0.

The reason these are special is that they don't follow the some of the normal rules for equality or compareTo

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    printComparisons("Float.NaN", Float.NaN);
    printComparisons("Double.NaN", Double.NaN);
    printComparisons("-0.0f", -0.0f);
    printComparisons("-0.0", -0.0);
}

private static void printComparisons(String desc, float v) {
    System.out.println("[ " + desc + " ]");
    System.out.println(v + " == " + v + " is " + (v == v));
    System.out.println(v + " != " + v + " is " + (v != v));
    System.out.println(v + " == 0.0  is " + (v == 0.0));
    System.out.println(v + " < 0 is " + (v < 0));
    System.out.println(v + " > 0 is " + (v > 0));
    System.out.println("Float.compareTo(" + v + ", 0) is " + Float.compare(v, 0));
    System.out.println();
}

private static void printComparisons(String desc, double v) {
    System.out.println("[ " + desc + " ]");
    System.out.println(v + " == " + v + " is " + (v == v));
    System.out.println(v + " != " + v + " is " + (v != v));
    System.out.println(v + " == 0.0  is " + (v == 0.0));
    System.out.println(v + " < 0 is " + (v < 0));
    System.out.println(v + " > 0 is " + (v > 0));
    System.out.println("Double.compareTo(" + v + ", 0) is " + Double.compare(v, 0));
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
[ Float.NaN ]
NaN == NaN is false
NaN != NaN is true
NaN == 0.0  is false
NaN < 0 is false
NaN > 0 is false
Float.compareTo(NaN, 0) is 1

[ Double.NaN ]
NaN == NaN is false
NaN != NaN is true
NaN == 0.0  is false
NaN < 0 is false
NaN > 0 is false
Double.compareTo(NaN, 0) is 1

[ -0.0f ]
-0.0 == -0.0 is true
-0.0 != -0.0 is false
-0.0 == 0.0  is true
-0.0 < 0 is false
-0.0 > 0 is false
Float.compareTo(-0.0, 0) is -1

[ -0.0 ]
-0.0 == -0.0 is true
-0.0 != -0.0 is false
-0.0 == 0.0  is true
-0.0 < 0 is false
-0.0 > 0 is false
Double.compareTo(-0.0, 0) is -1
```

In summary.

- NaN is not >, <, ==, >= or <= 0.0 but for `compareTo(NaN,0)` return 1
- 0.0 is == 0.0 but for compareTo(-0.0, 0.0) return -1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any cases for which this is true for primitive types.